# Vertically misaligned tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Vertically misaligned tags]

The vertical alignment of the tags is incorrect on Firefox. This is an exact duplicate of this problem on [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1004/vertically-misaligned-tags), and is probably the same as the one on [Web Apps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/search-input-element-needs-transparent-background-color-and-tag-anchor-misaligne) too. None of the other sites seem to have this problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.